# Redirect user to login page after clicking a favorites star in Django

Tags: jquery, django, authentication

I'm working on a media server, where each video will have a little star next to it. A JQuery event handler is attached to the button, so that clicking the button will result in an AJAX POST request to the server's favorites page, sending along the unique id of the video to be favorited. Then, the JQuery will toggle the image (if not favorited, a click will make the star "glow", if favorited, a click will make the star transparent again).

If the user is not logged in, they obviously cannot favorite videos. I want the user to be redirected to the login page when they click on the favorites button. However, the AJAX response means that a favorite button click from a non-authenticated user WILL toggle the favorites button image, which should not happen. The problem is, I don't know how I can short-circuit the JQuery function and prevent the toggle based on the user's login status.

Below is my favorites page, where the POST request is submitted.

```
@login_required
def favorite(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('id'):
        id = request.POST['id']
        id = id.rsplit('_')
        id = int(id[1])
        m = Media.objects.get(pk=id)
        m.favorited_by.add(request.user.get_profile())
        m.save()
    if request.META.has_key('HTTP_REFERRER'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERRER'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

and the JQuery

```
var imgSRC={'src1':'/static/images/star_off.png','src2':'/static/images/star_on.png'};
$('.favorites').live('click', function() {
    var img=$(this);
    id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    $.post('/favorite/', {"id": id}, function(data) {
        img.attr('src', imgSRC.src2);
        img.attr('class', 'favorites_on');
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I would prefer for the javascript to remain in its own file, rather than embedding the javascript into the django template. As such, I won't be able to use the template tag for user authentication. One solution I thought of was to search for a unique div layer that only exists when the user is logged in (the user's name is displayed at top right in the header after login), but this still doesn't solve my problem of doing this properly, while keeping my script separate from my template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make use of the [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method in your template:

```
$('.favorites').live('click', function() {
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
       //user is logged in, let's go!
       var img=$(this);
       id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
       console.log(id);
       $.post('/favorite/', {"id": id}, function(data) {
           img.attr('src', imgSRC.src2);
           img.attr('class', 'favorites_on');
       });
    {% else %}
       //not logged in, redirect to login page!
       window.location = "{% url your_login_url %}"; //what you named your login url in urls.py
    {% endif %}
});
```

## Update

You could send the status of your user to an external JS-file like this:

```
<!-- end of body -->
<script>
USER_STATUS = {{ request.user.is_authenticated }}; //normally true/false
LOGIN_URL = '{% url your_login_url %}'; //what you named your login url in urls.py
</script>
```

on top of your JS-file put these lines:

```
USER_STATUS = '';
LOGIN_URL = ''; // You'll never know when it changes ;)
```

then

```
$('.favorites').live('click', function() {
    if(USER_STATUS==true){
       //user is logged in, let's go!
       var img=$(this);
       id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
       console.log(id);
       $.post('/favorite/', {"id": id}, function(data) {
           img.attr('src', imgSRC.src2);
           img.attr('class', 'favorites_on');
       });
    } else {
       //not logged in, redirect to login page!
       window.location = LOGIN_URL; 
    }
});
```

i did test the javascript part, but without django. But i think it will get you started.

## Update 2

I used this in my `<script>`

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} USER_STATUS = 'true';{% else %} USER_STATUS =  'false';{% endif %}
 alert(USER_STATUS);
```

and it alerted `true`.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the javascript functions are in a separate functions.js file. I like your solution, but I would prefer not to add script to a bunch of templates if that's possible. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: The request variable is not available to the javascript, actually, I'm not sure how it's possible to format the inline script so that this works.

Comment: I added another update. I got this working in another purpose on my website where an object is passed through ajax and sent to an external JS-file.

Comment: Notice that i don't directly set my JS variables in my django if-structure anymore. (in update 2)